# Unable to connect localhost:8080/apex_admin

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex-5.1

I've installed Apex5.1 like 8 months ego and everything was fine.
I left it for like 2 months now and now i want to connect to my app, that is what i get.....

**Unable to connect**

Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at **localhost:8080/apex_admin**

any help please!

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a wrong URL. Should be

```
localhost:8080/apex
```

(if you want to connect as a developer) or

```
localhost:8080/apex/apex_admin
```

(if you want to connect as an admin).

Comment: Thanks! but Ihave tried both and I'm still getting the same error.